# how to add new event to flink CEP data stream?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, complex-event-processing, flink-cep

I am using flink 1.5.2 to solve a CEP problem.

my data is from a List, some other process will add new Event object to that list while system is running. It is not socket or network message. I've been reading the official site example. Here are the steps I imagine I should be doing.

1. create an DataStream using env.fromCollection(list);
2. define a Pattern pattern
3. get a PatternStream using CEP.pattern(data_stream, pattern)
4. use pattern_stream.select( ...implement select interface ...) to get the complex event result as a DataStream

But my input stream should be unbounded. I didn't find any add() method in DataStream<> object. How do I accomplish this? and also, do I need to tell DataStream<> when to clean up obsolete events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are only suitable as an input source for Flink when working with a bounded input set that's fixed up front, as when writing a test or just experimenting. If you want an unbounded stream you will need to choose a different source, such a socket or a message queuing system like Kafka.

Sockets are easy to work with for experimentation. On Linux and MacOS systems you can use

```
nc -lk 9999
```

to create a socket that Flink can bind to on port 9999, and whatever you provide as input to `nc` (netcat) will be streamed into your Flink job one line at a time. Netcat is also available for Windows, but isn't pre-installed.

However, you shouldn't plan to use sockets in production, as they can't be rewound (which is crucial for achieving accurate results with Flink during failure recovery).

Comment: I see, I do have a mqtt broker, but it has SSL. I will try to use flink to connect to that broker. Thanks

Comment: I have implemented a SourceFunction<> to test the flow. I add the source by env.addSource(). The run() method in my SourceFunction<> has a while loop which calls context.collect() to emit element. Finally I call the env.execute(). But the run() method is never called by anyone. I must have misunderstood how Flink CEP works. Is there a document which explain how to use CEP library to monitor the data stream?

Comment: I found the problem. I am using a loop to generate testing event and feed to my custom source. But I have a Thread.sleep(t) in the generator. When the Thread.sleep(t) is called, the whole program stuck. May be Thread.sleep() is conflicting with env.execute(); Is there anything I should be handling in a multi-threaded Source?

Comment: Oh, I was wrong. The new thread is running correctly, the real problem is the queue object. SourceFunction.run() gets a queue with no elements []. But the queue object which I am adding elements is not empty. I didn't know why there are two queue while I have only one source object.

Comment: I am guessing, the Source object needs to be serialize, and the de-serialize before run(). Thats why they are different instances.